# Intellij IDEA can't ctrl + v a name for 'Create New Class'

Tags: android-studio

I have Android Studio 2.3.1. When I create new class, In the edit box of name, I can't paste the new name!

My screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I074x.png

Has anyone ever encountered such a situation?

Previously it can be pasted！

Comment: You can use Ctrl + V in this form in IntelliJ IDEA. It seems to be an issue only for Android Studio. But what are you asking ? This isn't Android Studio's issue tracker. If you are looking for an alternative, type it manually.

Comment: check your keyboard language....it might be the problem.

Comment: @MohammadZarei it's for sure not a language issue.

Comment: Yes, have same issue on AS 2.3.2 Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Can paste fine in other fields.

Answer (score 1):

Check your installed plugins. I had mine problem resolved by disabling "Markdown Navigator". Also you can try to disable plugins one by one and restarting IDE to take effect.